# A question on the usage of both ... and

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I am not sure how to word the sentence correctly:

1. This book may be used both as a text and reference book.
2. This book may be used both as a text and a reference book.
3. This book may be used as both a text and reference book.
4. This book may be used as both a text and a reference book.

Which one(s) are correct?

Answer (score 1):

To me, none of them *sounds* right (I'm not a native English speaker). Though I have a feeling that pedantically 4 is right.

I would write:

> 5. This book may be used *both* as a text *and* **as** a reference book.

Because the structure after `both` and after `and` should be the same, it makes sense to have the word *as* either after both words, or before them.

Generally, when you say *both A and B*, *either A or B*, *neither A nor B*, it should follow the rule that *A* and *B* should be equivalent in terms of sentence structure, as well as that if the whole clause is replaced by either *A* or *B*, the sentence should remain correct. So 4 makes some sense while 1~3 don't.

> 1. This book may be used <s>both as a text and</s> reference book. (✖)
> 2. This book may be used <s>both as a text and</s> a reference book. (✖)
> 3. This book may be used as both a text and reference book. (✖, *a text* and *reference book* don't quite match)
> 4. This book may be used as both a text and a reference book. (✔, *a text* well matches *a reference book*)

However, do note that the meaning of sentence 4 (yours) and 5 (my sentence above) aren't exactly consistent. Sentence 5 tends to mean "*it can be used as a text, or a reference book*", whereas sentence 4 tends to mean "*it can be used as a text and a reference book **at the same time***".

As [pointed out][1] by *Andrew*, many native speakers say like sentence 2, so it could be safe to say so, everyone will understand.

[1]:

Comment: Your sentence "both as a text and as a reference" is what I would recommend as well, but nevertheless many native speakers will say "both as a text and a reference."

Comment: Actually, my textbook suggests sentence 1, "This book may be used both as a text and reference book."

Comment: @Andrew, what's the difference in meaning: "both as a text and a reference" vs "as both a text and a reference"?

Comment: @dan  Nothing at all.  The word order is personal preference.  I don't really agree with your textbook, though.